# UIPageViewController - view was not at the correct position initially

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uipageviewcontroller, ios-autolayout

I am using `UIPageViewController` to create the introduction pages of my app.

As the gif(I swiped to the 2nd view and swiped back to the 1st view):

[image]

My second page's view was not at the correct position initially. It's upper than it should be and dropped down later. However, if I swiped back, the first page's view was correct.

I guess it's because the `UIPageViewController` didn't load my 2nd view early enough, so the auto layout system was still calculating the position when the 2nd view already appeared. When I swiped back to the 1st view, since the view was already loaded, there was no such issue.(it's just my guess, I am not sure.)

I found I can use `2ndViewController.loadView()` as a workaround, but Apple's document discourages programmers to call this method directly. I also found calling this method directly is buggy.

How do I prevent this correctly?

Comment: Seems it can be corrected by setting constraints.

Comment: Actually, this happened after I set constraints. If I don't set constraint, the frames of my views are not what I want, but these frames are fixed from the beginning. Their position will not change afterwards

Comment: Can you show the constraints? I had a similar issue recently.

Comment: Fix top space from superview, it helped me.

Comment: Wow, it works!! I used to pin my top space to "Top Layout Guide", and it's fixed after I pin the top space to "superview". Is this a bug from iOS? or is this how it should be?

Comment: Written that as answer, so it helps others.

Comment: Accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Please explain why it works. I don't think it's a qualified answer if there is no explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting constraints, fix the view's top space from Superview.

Answer (score 0):

In func create view at index, let try my code

```
func pageTutorialAtIndex(index: Int) ->TestNodeController
{
    let pageContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TestNodeController") as! TestNodeController
    pageContentViewController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index
    return pageContentViewController

}
```